# Mathjax conflict with css opacity

Tags: html, css, mathjax

sometimes it works well:

[image: works well]

---

However, sometimes it looks like the formula is above the header layer..
[image: stange]

Is there any way to figure this out??

Comment: Do you have a link to a live sample?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger I kinda solved the problem by adding a `z-index` attribute to the header. Anyway, thanks :)

Comment: Glad you could solve it.